# flutter build Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath

Tags: android, flutter, dart

flutter build  Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath

How can I solve this problem

```
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/admin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/admin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.10/e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/admin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.10/b8af3fe6f1ca88526914929add63cf5e7c5049af/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/admin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.6.10/c118700e3a33c8a0d9adc920e9dec0831171925/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/admin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/admin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.10/e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/admin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.10/b8af3fe6f1ca88526914929add63cf5e7c5049af/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/admin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.6.10/c118700e3a33c8a0d9adc920e9dec0831171925/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
```

app build.grade setting

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

// crashlytics
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.mower_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    } 
    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            // 启用由Android Gradle插件执行的资源收缩
            minifyEnabled true 
            shrinkResources true 
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
            }
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

android > build.grade

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        // crashlytics
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can I solve this problem
This problem occurs every time a FLUTTER build occurs
flutter 2.10.1
Dart SDK version: 2.16.1 (stable) (Tue Feb 8 12:02:33 2022 +0100) on "windows_x64"

Answer (score 102, accepted):

In `app/build.gradle` change jdk7 to Java jdk8

before

```
dependencies {
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

after

```
dependencies {
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: thanks ... ```flutter build apk --release``` shows no Issue found but now it is stuck at ```Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...```

Comment: still got an error ( same issue ),

Comment: its solved for create new project but not solve for old project thats on migration version . dunno why .

Comment: The dependency was not there for me. It worked after I added it.

Answer (score 20):

The most upvoted answer by 51v4 **alone did not work for me**.
**Combining** his answer and [@anton-definit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615631/flutter-build-apk-runtime-jar-files-in-the-classpath-should-have-the-same-vers/73957935#73957935) , I've got the solution that worked for me. There were no warning messages shown.

1. Upgrade the **jdk** version from `jdk7` to `jdk8` in `android/build.gradle`. Should look like this

```
dependencies {
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}
```

2. Upgrade the **Kotlin** version to `1.7.10` in `android/build.gradle`. Should look like this `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'`
3. Upgrade the **Android Gradle plugin** to `7.3.0` in `android/build.gradle`. Should look like this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'`
4. Upgrade the **Gradle** version to `7.5.1` in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. Should look like this. `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip`
5. Delete the folder `C:\Users\[user_name_here]\.gradle`. If you got any errors when deleting the `.gradle` folder, open **Windows Task Manager** and terminate the **OpenJDK platform binary** then retry deleting. Finally run `flutter clean` in the terminal.
6. Run your app. **Wait patiently, It will take over 10 minutes for re-installing the gradle wrapper & settings** and the `flutter build apk` will be completed without warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Add following to `android/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies { 
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1' 
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In android/build.gradle change gradle:7.1.2 to gradle:7.3.1

**Before**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"  
    }
```

**After**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Run:

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```