# flutter build apk - Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

similar issue [flutter build Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71347054/flutter-build-runtime-jar-files-in-the-classpath-should-have-the-same-version-t)

solved only for new project https://stackoverflow.com/a/71362765/8122500 but when i tried on old project, the error is still facing on me. also i have tried with **flutter clean**, **restart device**, etc

```
➜  xxxx git:(master) ✗ flutter build apk --release      

 Building with sound null safety 

w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /Users/yogiarifwidodo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.6.10/e80fe6ac3c3573a80305f5ec43f86b829e8ab53d/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    /Users/yogiarifwidodo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.7.10/1ef73fee66f45d52c67e2aca12fd945dbe0659bf/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
    /Users/yogiarifwidodo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
    /Users/yogiarifwidodo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
e: /Users/yogiarifwidodo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.7.10/1ef73fee66f45d52c67e2aca12fd945dbe0659bf/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/yogiarifwidodo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/yogiarifwidodo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /Users/yogiarifwidodo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.6.10/e80fe6ac3c3573a80305f5ec43f86b829e8ab53d/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    /Users/yogiarifwidodo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.7.10/1ef73fee66f45d52c67e2aca12fd945dbe0659bf/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
    /Users/yogiarifwidodo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
    /Users/yogiarifwidodo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           22.3s
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk (25.7MB).
```

my configuration

```
/x/android/build.gradle

ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
...
...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
...
...
/x/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
...
...
/x/android/app/build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}
```

my engine

```
➜  first_app flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale en-ID)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at /Users/yogiarifwidodo/dev/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (8 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/yogiarifwidodo/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/yogiarifwidodo/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.0-insider)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code - Insiders.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.48.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 104.0.5112.101

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

```
➜  JavaVirtualMachines ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B Jun 27  2021 zulu-11.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B Sep  3 11:58 zulu-17.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B May  1  2021 zulu-8.jdk
➜  JavaVirtualMachines pwd
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue. Here is how I fixed it:

1. Upgrade the **Kotlin** version to `1.7.10` in `android/app/build.gradle`. Should look like this `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'`
2. Upgrade the **Android Gradle plugin** to `7.3.0` in `android/app/build.gradle`. Should look like this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'`
3. In the terminal navigate to the android folder `cd android` and run `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=7.5.1` to upgrade the **Gradle** version to `7.5.1`. This will change the distribution url in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to point to the correct gradle distribution.
4. Delete the folder `android/.gradle` and run `flutter clean` in the terminal
5. Run your app and the warnings should be gone.

For future reference, a good place to find the supported combinations of the **Android Gradle plugin** and **Gradle** is here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Simply replacing `jdk7` with `jdk8` in `android/app/build.gradle` as suggested, did not work for me. In fact, it could be best to just remove this dependency altogether because it is added by default by the **Android Gradle plugin**. Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101373

Comment: Worked for me, spent 5 hours and found this to my solace.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me to replace **jdk7 with jdk8** in **app/build.gradle** file under the dependencies

```
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

with

```
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```