# encountered warning error: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

[image]

In project build.gradle:

```
buildscript = ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' 

// dependencies 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

In app build.gradle:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: Please don't post error logs as images. See [ask] for more info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter build apk - Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615631/flutter-build-apk-runtime-jar-files-in-the-classpath-should-have-the-same-vers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution I just edit upgrade my jdk to 8 in android>app>buildGradle>dependencies:

```
dependencies {  
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version
```

to

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10"
```

Comment: I already done it , still got the errors

Answer (score 0):

Try updating classpath gradle version in android/build.gradle
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x") maybe update a more recent version (3.0.1 > 4.0.1), some times this cause problems. After do this, go to android folder in the console (cd android) and clean chache (./gradlew clean),